# Split one JSON return into several objects

Tags: javascript, json, object, highcharts

So, I've been looking at this for a couple hours and am out of ideas. My app is returning a single JSON object, and I need to parse the 4 data sets out of it and make 3 charts and a table. For the life of me I can't figure out how to "extract" each part. The JSON looks like:

```
{
   "allele":{
      "12426597":{
         "??":4,
         "CC":3,
         "TT":4,
         "CT":12
      },
      "878198":{
         "??":4,
         "AA":1,
         "AC":15,
         "CC":3
      },
      "6447271":{
         "??":4,
         "GG":14,
         "AG":5
      }
   },
   "haplo":{
      "CT,AG,AC":3,
      "TT,GG,AC":1,
      "CC,GG,CC":1,
      "TT,AG,CC":1,
      "TT,GG,CC":1
   },
   "exercise":"p1"
}
```

I need to grab the data just for the three key's/IDs (12426597,878198, 6447271) and make one bar chart for each of those (requiring a [data transformation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15731391/need-to-count-json-key-occurence-value) <== see). Then I need to plug it into Highcharts...their API calling for an ordered arrays for the keys and values.

I thought about first making an array of the IDs:

```
var snpsObj = data.allele_frequency; // data returned from $.getJSON
var snpList = [];

for (prop in snpsObj) {
    if (!snpsObj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        continue;
    }
    snpList.push(prop);
}
```

Which does get me the wanted array. And then accessing the "sub" keys like:

```
snpsObj.snpList[0];
```

...to return hopefully, something like:

```
{
   "CC" : 23,
   "CT" : 36,
   "TT" : 12,
}
```

But that doesn't work at all.  The most I could get was a return of something like:

```
allele_frequency : [object Object ]
```

I know there's something basic I'm just forgetting in my head-cold-fogged mind...  Any suggestions?

Highcharts needs the keys and labels formatted in arrays, like:

categories: ['C', 'T']
data: [ 3, 9] // C=3, T=9

Comment: Shouldn't you be pushing the actual value instead of the property name `snpList.push(snpsObj[prop]);`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to access

```
snpsObj[ snpList[0] ]
```

by using [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators), `snpsObj.snpList[0]` would try to get the "snpList" *property* of your `snpsObj` object.

Btw, instead of your for-in-loop to create the array with property names, you might want to use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) (even if you need to shim it to support old browsers).